How were unruly wives dealt with by the Beit Din?
I have heard that if a husband wants to keep his wife bound, the Rambam would say the Beit Din should take him out back and beat him. My question is, what remedies did the Beit Din have for a wife who was also bad, say not wanting to care for the home or fulfill their marital duties?

I’m asking how they were dealt with in Halacha and in the communities.

The prohibition on divorcing a woman against her will was one of the decrees or Rabbenu Gershon and in effect for Ashkenazim for 1000 years. (It technically expired recently).
These are the remedies:
Divorce her against her will,
Reduce the value of her ketuba for each week she doesn't service her husband
Allow the husband to have a second wife
There are opinions that allow husband or beis din to beat her

Thank you, I appreciate the answer.

A rebelious wife is called מוֹרֶדֶת / moredes. There are many details of laws, some are listed in Mishneh Torah 14.8-14 and 14.16. There are other sources available on Sefaria if one performs search for entry מורדת.

Thank you, I appreciate the answer.
